# SketchUP: How to to resize only one dimension of the model and leave others as is

Tags: resize, sketchup

I am somewhat new to sketchup - I have used it for just simple woodworking.

I have a problem with this model.

My research says this should be very easy.

I want to resize the short side from 1' 11 9/16  -to-  1' 11 1/4". I just want to shorten those six horizontal rods which are a little too long, not to scale anything else.

Every time I do this it resizes the long side and scales the model down.

Here is what I tried that does not work:

- Use the tape tool, resize the short side
- Group the entire model, Use the tape tool, resize the short side
- Explode model to just a component, Use the tape tool, resize the short side
- Explode the entire model, Use the tape tool, resize the short side

I could just redraw the model again in about an hour, but there must be a way to do this. Can you advise on a better way?
[image]

EDIT1:

I tried to undo everything down to the basics.

I resized the vertical frame and saved a horizontal 2x4

I selected the long 2x4 and resized with the Tape tool to 13' 3 5/16".

Notice that the base of the vertical frame got resized from 1' 11 1/4" to 4' 1/2"

Am I making these componets incorrectly?
[image]

EDIT2:

I exploded the frame into two vert 2x4s and one horiz 2x4 because I noticed that when I modified the frame as a component OR the horizontal separately it would distort the 2x4's dimensions. I deleted everything else.

This time, when I modified the horiz 2x4 the dimensions of the vert 2x4 remained the same, but notice the horiz: It shrunk!  The horiz is not 1.5 x 3.5 anymore.

So let me rephrase my original question: How do I tell Sketchup to modify my models overall dimensions >WITHOUT< changing the dimensions what the model is made from (namely 2x4s in this case).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If I understood, you want only shorter pink part. Hide one of the grey-green-blue frames (make them a componet, too) to make the ends of all pink parts free. Then push the pink parts axially shorter. Use the Pull tool.

Before pushing make a marker with the tape measure to the parts which need shortening. You can also cut a piece off sideways. It's shown later.

Then make the hidden frame visible and move it to its new place.

In paid version of SketcUP there's available boolean combinations (subtract, union, intersect). You could with them subtract the needed piece a little easier.

An example: The horisontal part must be shortened a preknown amount.

[image]

Hide one of the vertical parts to keep it safe. Draw a rectangle which covers the piece to be removed:

[image]

Take the pull tool and push the rectangle off through the bar. Use the erasing rubber to remove possible remnants (=end curve). Shortening like this (=sideways) doesn't need tape measure, you can dimension the rectangle directly.

[image]

Unhide the vertical bar

[image]

select the vertical bar and move it to the green axis direction until it snaps with the shortened horizontal bar:

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  I think I understand you.  If you look at the last image what I'm hoping to do is use the tape tool from end of red to end of other red and enter the dimensions I want.  Then SU will pull the piece in WITHOUT scaling it.  Imagine I cut the horizontal piece of wood in half and then I just push the two vertical 2x4s closer and nail them together.  I made the whole shorter, but they are still 2x4s.  SU is shrinking the 2x4s.  I am using the web base app.

Comment: @Marinaio SU cannot know that only the length of the horizontal piece must be shortened if you do something else than just shorten it. You need parametric CAD if you want to set up scaling and alignment rules. I'll add the shortening to my answer.

Comment: @user287001 to be honest i can not for earth of me understand how it takes and hour to remake? It takes less than that to make a fully parametric model with all fasteners. Even if the GUI is really unoptimal for this.

Comment: @joojaa When I opened SU first time, it took easily a hour to make anything that resembled something.. The questioner obviously has more models which need the same fixing => a magic bullet is more than welcome.

Comment: @user287001 which is why i wonder every time when people say that SU is very easy

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you don't have the correct orientation selected when you try to scale (resize) the model.

With the whole model selected click the scale tool and then click the node at the center of the side you wish to push.

[image]

Now either type a decimal scale value (.5 for 50%, 2 for 200%) or drag mouse until its there. Click again to set it.

For this fine adjustment you will want to scale the short side by .98673740

I got this by converting your before and after measurements to a fraction and dividing.

1'11 and 9/16" = 377/16"

1'11 and 4/16" = 372/16"

Comment: Thanks.  I tried that.  But that scales the entire model.  I don't want to change the scale, per se.  I want to fix a mistake in the short side measurement.  My understanding was that all the short sides would move in and the length of the unit would not change.

Comment: once a given element is actually drawn and completed, changing the dimension value forces a total model rescale - that's the intentional logic in SketchUp. To change an individual value, you'll need to move or redraw those elements to the correct dimension - the answer from @User287001 is spot-on.